# Jquery and global variable scope issue between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var english = "";
            var spanish = "";

            $.get("./gamelist-english.txt",function(data){
                english = data;
                });

            $.get("./gamelist-spanish.txt",function(data){
                spanish = data;
                });

        $('#compare').mergely({
            cmsettings: { readOnly: true, lineNumbers: true },
            lhs: function(setValue) {
                setValue(english);
            },
            rhs: function(setValue) {
                setValue(spanish);
            }
        });

    });
```

(by the way, I'm using mergely library here, but I don't think this matters)

The problem I have is that both variables, "spanish" and "english", are not global, so $('#compare').mergely can't get their values (it says they're both empty, but that's not true). How can I fix this? I thought that by declaring any variables outside of any function they are automatically made global, but apparently that's not working, or I'm a bit lost.

Thank you very much.

Comment: They don't need to be global. The scope for them is fine. (You are declaring them inside the anonymous function you pass to `ready`, not as globals).

Comment: ^^ What @Quentin said. Moreover, not making them globals is a Good Thing™. :-)

Comment: @Quentin If I write "console.log(english)" inside the GET function, I can get the value, however, if I do the same thing inside .mergely(), console.log does not print anything :S If the scope is alright, what's failling? (T. J. Crowder answered)

Comment: @Arturo — See the duplicate question.

Comment: @Quentin thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that they're not globals is not the problem. The scope you have them in is fine.

The problem is that you're calling `mergely` **before** you have values in those variables, because ajax is **asynchronous**. Instead, wait for the calls to complete:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var english = "";
    var spanish = "";

    $.when(
        $.get("./gamelist-english.txt",function(data){
            english = data;
        }),
        $.get("./gamelist-spanish.txt",function(data){
            spanish = data;
        })
    ).then(function() {
        $('#compare').mergely({
            cmsettings: { readOnly: true, lineNumbers: true },
            lhs: function(setValue) {
                setValue(english);
            },
            rhs: function(setValue) {
                setValue(spanish);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can avoid having those variables at all, though, because when you use `$.when` the callback receives the values from the two promises; note that since it's a `$.get`, the value is an array with the data as the first item in the array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.when(
        $.get("./gamelist-english.txt"),
        $.get("./gamelist-spanish.txt")
    ).then(function(english, spanish) {
        $('#compare').mergely({
            cmsettings: { readOnly: true, lineNumbers: true },
            lhs: function(setValue) {
                setValue(english[0]); // <== Note the [0]
            },
            rhs: function(setValue) {
                setValue(spanish[0]); // <== Note the [0]
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes! This worked. I didn't think about that. Thank you very much!